# nginx PHP slash before each GET parameter

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

When I do `print_r($_GET)` I get a slash before the parameter.

`Array ( [video_name] => /onajr ) 1`

nginx conf
`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?video_name=$uri;`

Why is that and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `nginx` URIs begin with a leading slash. If you really must extract the URI without the leading slash, something like this may work for you:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?video_name=$1 last;
}
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: which is faster rewrite or try files?

Comment: Your original configuration is more efficient, if you can live with the leading slash in your PHP.